# UWP import third party code signing certficate fails

Tags: cordova, uwp, visual-studio-cordova, code-signing-certificate, sideloading

I have build a Windows 10 Cordova application and plan to sideload it as its an enterprise application built for internal use.

During testing,we were using the Apache Corodva certificate to sign the package.

Now, we are trying to use the company's code signing certificate to sign it for production.But getting the following issue:

> The Manifest Designer could not import the certificate.
>
> The certificate you selected is not valid for signing because it is either expired or has another issue"

I have through links which talk about the properties that need to be set for Visual studio to accept it and followed the instructions.

Anything else i am missing out.

Answer (score 2):

We are at the same situation (but the enterprise code signing cert is not expired), and have to skip signing checks in order to import the cert in `Manifest Designer`.

Open the project file (.csproj), and add the following line under the first `PropertyGroup` element.

```
<EnableSigningChecks>false</EnableSigningChecks>
```

And the app can be side-loaded successfully. Hope this helps in your case.

Comment: Hi @kennyzx, I'm using a WPF application that is packaged in a .msix installer (via the Windows Application Packaging Project) and your solution works. What exactly does that parameter do? Does it just turn off the signing check or does it affect the signing process?

Comment: Hi @Puty, pls check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/br230260(v=vs.140)#decide-which-validation-checks-you-want-visual-studio-to-perform). Not sure what is wrong with my signing cert but this apparently skips some validation checks.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this issue. I think the issue with my certificate (bought on SSL.com) was that the `Basic Constraints` extension was not set. This is one of the validations omitted when disabling `EnableSigningChecks`. I don't think this has side effects, this extension just tells the certificate type, [as explained here](https://www.pkisolutions.com/basic-constraints-certificate-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

> plan to sideload it as its an enterprise application built for internal use.

If the app is submitted through Dev Center, the Store will automatically maintain the app’s certificate and package without requiring maintaining manually. 
However using the way of sideloading you need to maintain manually the package and certificate once the app has any update. For your issue, you need to check if your certificate has expired or has some other issues.

If you don't mind submitting your app through Dev Center,  there are some options to recommend for you:

1. Set your app to be hidden in the Store, the hidden apps can be only available with the direct link but not been discovered in the Store.
2. Publish your app to the private store in the Microsoft Store for Business, in this way all employees in your organization can view and download the app.
3. Use LOB app which can be published directly to the enterprises for volume acquisition via Microsoft Store for Business, without being broadly available in the Store.

You can get information from the document : [Distribute apps using your private store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-apps-from-your-private-store) and [Distribute LOB apps to enterprises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises).